# Get JSON script code with pushing to heatmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, google-maps

I have a script that makes a database call and then filters the results. After filtering it pushes it to an array and shows it on a map.

Here is my function:

```
function getDriving() {
    pointArray.length = 0;
    markers.length = 0;
    var todayval = new Date();


    var url = $('#map').data('request-url2');
    $.getJSON(url,
        function (data) {
            $.each(data,
                function (i, item) {

                    markers.push({
                        'location': new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude),
                        'map': map,
                        'weight': item.Speed,
                        'radius': 10,
                        'date': item.CurrentDateTime,
                        'imei': item.Imei
                    });
                });
            imei = parseInt($('#selectVehicles').val());

            var startValue = $('#startDate').val().split("/");
            var endValue = $('#endDate').val().split("/");
            var valDateStart = new Date(startValue[2], startValue[1] - 1, startValue[0]);
            var valDateEnd = new Date(endValue[2], endValue[1] - 1, endValue[0]);

            filtered = markers.filter(function (marker) {
                var getDate = marker.date.match(/\d/g).join('');
                var markerDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));
                return ((markerDate >= valDateStart && markerDate <= valDateEnd) && marker.imei === imei);
            });
            var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(filtered);

            heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: pointArray
            });
            heatmap.setMap(map);
        });
};
```

It works well, but I want to know if everything is okay with the code or how I can improve it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Scope of Variables

Unless `imei` is used outside of the code in your post (which would be grounds for making it off-topic), then you should declare it as local to the function using [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) (or [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) if you want it to have block scope. The same is true for `filtered` and `heatmap`. That way those variables won't be global, which could cause confusion if you did use `var` to declare a variable inside a function but not before that.

For more information on that topic, see the section **Keep your scopes close and your scope even closer** on [this page](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/).

#### Accessing DOM elements multiple times via `$()`

DOM lookups are slow. It is wise to cache them once in a variable and then refer to the variable when needed. This is also mentioned in [the aforementioned article](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/) under the section **Cache DOM Lookups**

Those lookups could be added above the function (possibly assigned in a DOM ready function like jQuery's [`$(function(){})`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3), though it is argued that isn't necessary with modern browsers):

```
var map = $('#map');
var selectedVehicles = $('#selectVehicles');
var startDate = $('#startDate');
var endDate = $('#endDate');
```

Then those variables can be used later on when the function is run- for example:

> ```
> var url = $('#map').data('request-url2');
> ```

Can be updated to use `map`:

```
var url = map.data('request-url2');
```

And `map` could also be used when setting up the Google Map instance, since presumably that is the same element used for the map.

#### Using parseInt() without a radix

If you are going to use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), it is wise to specify the radix using the second parameter - unless you are using a unique number system like hexidecimal, octal, etc. then specify 10 for decimal numbers.

> **Always specify this parameter** to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting the value to 10.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters)</sup>

So I would update the line:

> ```
> imei = parseInt($('#selectVehicles').val());
> ```

To pass the radix 10:

```
imei = parseInt($('#selectVehicles').val(), 10);
```

That way, if a value like `022` is entered, it isn't interpreted as the octal value (I.e. Decimal number `18`).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things that can be improved, especially when working with inputs, then use `keyup` or `blur` so you don't have to do a lot of computation when `getDriving()` is called.

I'll focus on `$.each()`: this method is extremely slow and can be solved with native JavaScript methods like [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
function (data) {
     imei = parseInt($('#selectVehicles').val());

     var startValue = $('#startDate').val().split("/");
     var endValue = $('#endDate').val().split("/");
     var valDateStart = new Date(startValue[2], startValue[1] - 1, startValue[0]);
     var valDateEnd = new Date(endValue[2], endValue[1] - 1, endValue[0]);

    filtered = data.reduce(function(arr, item){
       var getDate = item.CurrentDateTime.match(/\d/g).join('');
       var itemDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));

       if((itemDate >= valDateStart && itemDate <= valDateEnd) && item.Imei === imei){
          arr.push({
             'location': new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude),
             'map': map,
             'weight': item.Speed,
             'radius': 10,
             'date': item.CurrentDateTime,
             'imei': item.Imei
         });
      }
      return arr;
    }, []);

    var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(filtered);

    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
       data: pointArray
    });
    heatmap.setMap(map);
}
```

I ended up removing the `filter` as well; when you get the `data`, you can just reduce the array into the actual output you want and then just check if it satisfies the condition and if not then do not add it to the list.

Also, I noticed that variables `imei`, `startValue`, `endValue`, `varDateStart` and `valDateEnd` never change value so just put them above the `array.reduce()`.

Comment: `imei` and other values can be changed

Comment: You have a very short time frame to change it while the reduce function is executing, so you could potentially disable them meanwhile. Your filter function also suffers from this side effect, the code is working the same way.